# Interaction between WPA_Supplicant and Netplan's YAML Files (if any) - 20.04 Wireless Networking

Tags: networking, server, wireless, 20.04, raspberrypi

Do WPA_Supplicant.Conf and Netplan YAML files negatively interact?  E.g. should I only be defining wireless APs in one and not the other?

Trying to figure out why my wifi won't work on Ubuntu Server 20.04 (on RaspPI 4 Model B - latest firmware and drivers installed, interface is up using ip link set wlan0 up, and have configured fixed-cable ethernet in netplan 99_wired.yaml.  Unplugged ethernet so that I shouldn't be encountering the auto-switching logic that defaults to wired (I forget the name of that at the moment).  Teed two network blocks into my WPA supplicant file using wpa_passphrase and removed the #psk with the password. Added priorities, country block, ctrl_interface, and update_config=1.  Unable to bring wifi up and start the wpa_supplicant.

I was wondering if I need to remove the wifis block in my 10_wifi.yaml file?  Or add my wifis block to my 99_Wired.yaml file?  Or leave out wifis altogether in netplan yamls because WPA_Supplicant handles it?

Really wish that Ubuntu Server had an easier way to configure wifi - certain projects in the house benefit from server rather than desktop images.

Thanks for your time and patience.

EDIT: even more confusing is from man netplan (quoted here to facilitate discussion):
"Properties for device type wifis:
Note that systemd-networkd does not natively support wifi, so you need wpasupplicant installed if you let the networkd renderer handle wifi."

Okay, clear enough, but then it says...
"access-points (mapping)
This provides pre-configured connections to NetworkManager."

Wtf? so what if I try to add a wifi without specifying access-points, it will complain about access points not specified.  But if I add the access point and password, wth did I put it in wpa_supplicant.conf, and which one is used at runtime?

Comment: Without seeing your .yaml files, it's difficult to assist. Edit your question and show us `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and any WPA Supplicant files that you've changed.

Comment: See my answer below - that $#!^ takes way too much time otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't worth the time to troubleshoot, TBH, so leaving this here for others.  I reimaged the microSD card following these steps:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#3-wifi-or-ethernet

To me it is a bit unacceptable that this is the only easy way to make wifi work (during installation/system setup using network-config file).  But it's a workaround and I can now harden the system and actually start the project I intended to do on the Pi in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am working through this myself right now, so I apologize in advance if any information is less than 100% accurate, but I can answer at least a few of your questions definitely:

- `netplan` can run WIFI through `systemd-networkd` just fine.  I'm using it RN to write this and watch TV.
- `netplan` creates a differently named unit file than the one used by `wpa_supplicant` (e.g. `netplan-wpa-wlan0.service` vs `wpa_supplicant@.service`
- It does not look as if the `netplan-wpa-ifname.service` will collide with `wpa_supplicant@ifname.service`, as it is named something completely different, avoiding the `wpa_supplicant@ifname.service` naming convention altogether.
- Therefore, you do not need to start `wpa_supplicant@ifname.service` at all when using `netplan`
- In the vein of the last answer, you do not need to create a/any `.conf` file(s) in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/.` if you're using `netplan`, it extrapolates all the info it needs from your `.yaml` file in `/etc/netplan/.`.
- `netplan` may need the `wpa_supplicant` package installed in order to invoke it during authentication to your SSID/AP, but I did just stop `wpa_supplicant.service` and my WIFI is still working

Sorry I don't have a better answer for that last one, as I am literally working through this right now as I write this.  I saw that your question(s) hadn't been answered, and thought it incumbent to do my part in helping the community.

You could test whether or not you need `wpa_supplicant` present by simply disabling `wpa_supplicant.service` before trying to connect to your SSID with `netplan`.  However, uninstalling it might be dicey, as Ubuntu has a tendency to remove huge meta-packages when people go uninstalling things that are intrinsic to their usage (e.g. uninstalling `network-manager` removes things like `ubuntu-desktop`, `ubuntucinnamon-desktop`, etc. so, disabling `NetworkManager` via `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` in order to use `systemd-networkd` is far less painful).

Tip: the `systemd-networkd`, `netplan.io` and `wpa_supplicant` man files are extremely informative, if perennially verbose.  Good luck!